# What methods can be used to secure web services?

Tags: security, soap, service

I'm interested to know what methods people use to secure their webservices from unauthorized web service consumers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a protocol specifically for web services security [WS-Security](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security). I've used parts of it in the past but at the time there was not a lot of support for it in .Net so it was a lot of work.

Currently with .Net I use SOAP Extension Headers. I have one web service call to authenticate and get a session token and then include that token in a SOAP header for every subsequent call, somewhat similar to this [example](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/experts/article.php/c5479). Of course all the request must travel over TLS to keep them from being compromised.

Answer (score 1):

I usually require either a user id/password to be sent each time, or return a token from the first authenticated connection that can be used subsequently.

Nothing fancy. Pretty similar to standard web app login.

Answer (score 1):

I've used both SOAP headers and method parameters to pass user credentials -- .NET makes using the SOAP headers pretty easy, but I had issues with this using Java (several months back).  I also do some IP-based filtering if the service is not intended for client (browser) use, but rather from backend web servers.  Public, browser consumable web services are often protected by session cookies -- i.e, requires a valid logon to the web site, then the standard session authentication mechanism is used for requests via AJAX to web services.

Answer (score 0):

You can use network appliances such as IBM's DataPower or Vordel if you don't want to handle in your own application.